Unable to connect to MongoDB using Mongoose and Nodemon
When I run nodemon server in backend directory of my project using the VS Code terminal, I get the following error:
[nodemon] 3.1.0
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,cjs,json
[nodemon] starting `node server.js`
Server is running on port: 5000
H:\Project\project\backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:875
    err = new ServerSelectionError();
          ^

MongooseServerSelectionError: Could not connect to any servers in your MongoDB Atlas cluster. One common reason is that you're trying to access the database from an IP that isn't whitelisted. Make sure your current IP address is on your Atlas cluster's IP whitelist: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/security-whitelist/
    at _handleConnectionErrors (H:\Project\project\backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:875:11)
    at NativeConnection.openUri (H:\Project\project\backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:826:11) {
  reason: TopologyDescription {
    type: 'ReplicaSetNoPrimary',
    servers: Map(3) {
      'ac-zltfugd-shard-00-01.jmuakrd.mongodb.net:27017' => ServerDescription {
        address: 'ac-zltfugd-shard-00-01.jmuakrd.mongodb.net:27017',
        type: 'Unknown',
        hosts: [],
        passives: [],
        arbiters: [],
        tags: {},
        minWireVersion: 0,
        maxWireVersion: 0,
        roundTripTime: -1,
        lastUpdateTime: 12802051,
        lastWriteDate: 0,
        error: MongoNetworkError: connect ETIMEDOUT 35.188.3.14:27017
            at connectionFailureError (H:\Project\project\backend\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connect.js:353:20)   
            at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (H:\Project\project\backend\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connect.js:268:44)    
            at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:642:26)
            at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:527:28)
            at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:157:8)
            at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:122:3)
            at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
          [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(1) { 'ResetPool' },
          [cause]: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 35.188.3.14:27017
              at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1187:16) {
            errno: -4039,
            code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
            syscall: 'connect',
            address: '35.188.3.14',
            port: 27017
          }
        },
        topologyVersion: null,
        setName: null,
        setVersion: null,
        electionId: null,
        logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null,
        primary: null,
        me: null,
        '$clusterTime': null
      },
      'ac-zltfugd-shard-00-02.jmuakrd.mongodb.net:27017' => ServerDescription {
        address: 'ac-zltfugd-shard-00-02.jmuakrd.mongodb.net:27017',
        type: 'Unknown',
        hosts: [],
        passives: [],
        arbiters: [],
        tags: {},
        minWireVersion: 0,
        maxWireVersion: 0,
        roundTripTime: -1,
        lastUpdateTime: 12802059,
        lastWriteDate: 0,
        error: MongoNetworkError: connect ETIMEDOUT 35.192.144.244:27017
            at connectionFailureError (H:\Project\project\backend\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connect.js:353:20)   
            at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (H:\Project\project\backend\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connect.js:268:44)    
            at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:642:26)
            at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:527:28)
            at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:157:8)
            at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:122:3)
            at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
          [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(1) { 'ResetPool' },
          [cause]: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 35.192.144.244:27017
              at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1187:16) {
            errno: -4039,
            code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
            syscall: 'connect',
            address: '35.192.144.244',
            port: 27017
          }
        },
        topologyVersion: null,
        setName: null,
        setVersion: null,
        electionId: null,
        logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null,
        primary: null,
        me: null,
        '$clusterTime': null
      },
      'ac-zltfugd-shard-00-00.jmuakrd.mongodb.net:27017' => ServerDescription {
        address: 'ac-zltfugd-shard-00-00.jmuakrd.mongodb.net:27017',
        type: 'Unknown',
        hosts: [],
        passives: [],
        arbiters: [],
        tags: {},
        minWireVersion: 0,
        maxWireVersion: 0,
        roundTripTime: -1,
        lastUpdateTime: 12802092,
        lastWriteDate: 0,
        error: MongoNetworkError: connect ETIMEDOUT 35.202.144.107:27017
            at connectionFailureError (H:\Project\project\backend\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connect.js:353:20)   
            at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (H:\Project\project\backend\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connect.js:268:44)    
            at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:642:26)
            at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:527:28)
            at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:157:8)
            at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:122:3)
            at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
          [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(1) { 'ResetPool' },
          [cause]: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 35.202.144.107:27017
              at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1187:16) {
            errno: -4039,
            code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
            syscall: 'connect',
            address: '35.202.144.107',
            port: 27017
          }
        },
        topologyVersion: null,
        setName: null,
        setVersion: null,
        electionId: null,
        logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null,
        primary: null,
        me: null,
        '$clusterTime': null
      }
    },
    stale: false,
    compatible: true,
    heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
    localThresholdMS: 15,
    setName: 'atlas-r9uvf5-shard-0',
    maxElectionId: null,
    maxSetVersion: null,
    commonWireVersion: 0,
    logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null
  },
  code: undefined
}
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...

This is the code in my server.js:
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

require('dotenv').config();

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

const uri = process.env.ATLAS_URI;
mongoose.connect(uri, {});

const connection = mongoose.connection;
connection.once('open', () => {
    console.log("MongoDB database connection established successfully");
})

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on port: ${port}`);
});

I have a database user with atlasAdmin@admin in MongoDB and the IP address in the network access tab is set to 0.0.0.0/0, yet I'm still unable to connect. Why am I not able to connect to my cluster using Mongoose?

I suggest to also pass the following connection parameter: { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true } instead of an empty object

"Could not connect to any servers in your MongoDB Atlas cluster. One common reason is that you're trying to access the database from an IP that isn't whitelisted. Make sure your current IP address is on your Atlas cluster's IP whitelist:"
This part of the error message indicates that your current IP address isn't whitelisted in your mogodb atlas database. So go to your mongodb atlas and make sure to add your current IP address to the whitelist or you can allow the "access from anywhere" option, but it's not recommended to make this.

I've done this already. I mentioned at the bottom of my post I added "access from anywhere" and it still didn't resolve my issue.
